# Can I compare resultsets like this? I'm facing the below error

Tags: java, loops, jdbc, resultset

I have 2 ResultSets. 1st ResultSet contains the records from table1 from database1 and 2nd ResultSet contains the records from table2 from database2. I need a list of records from resultset1 which are not present in resultSet2. For this I wrote this logic but it is not working and throwing me the following error.

java.sql.SQLException: Invalid operation for read only resultset: deleteRow

```
if ( table1ResultSet != null )
  {
    while ( table1ResultSet.next() )
    {
      final String table1Record = table1ResultSet.getString( 1 );

      if ( table2ResultSet != null )
      {
        while ( table2ResultSet.next() )
        {
          final String table2Record = table2ResultSet.getString( 1 );

          if ( table1Record.toString().equalsIgnoreCase( table2Record.toString() ) )
          {
            table1ResultSet.deleteRow();

            break;
          }
        }
      }
    }


  }

  return table1ResultSet;
```

Comment: On the first iteration of `table1ResultSet`, you've moved the cursor of `table2ResultSet` beyond it's last result. You need to reset the cursor back to "before start" - of course, you could just query the second database for the result from each row in `table1ResultSet`

Comment: Do you really want to delete records from the table1 of database1?

Comment: I want a list of records from table1 which are not present in table2

Answer (score 1):

That exception says what the problem is - your result set doesn't support delete. In  order to have updateable result set there are some requirements:

When you prepare statement did you make it with ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE?

A query can select from only a single table without any join operations.
The query must select all non-nullable columns and all columns that do not have a default value. A query cannot use "SELECT * ". Cannot select derived columns or aggregates such as the SUM or MAX of a set of columns.

You might want to move the results sets into Java sets before working doing what you are doing though because using deleteRow will actually delete the row from the database (unless that's the expected result)

There is another problem with your code though. Even if delete works your code will fail on the second iteration of result set 1 because you never reset table2ResultSet and for the second iteration there won't be more results in table2resulset.

But on top of all that. Why would you go through all that hussle and get all that rows that you don't need instead of doing it with one single query like:

```
select * from table 1 where id not in select id from table 2
```

or

```
delete from table 1 where id not in select id from table 2
```

if that's the goal

Comment: Here I'm dealing with 2 databases. So cannot do like this. My intention is to get the list of records from table1 which are not preset in table2. table1 and table2 are in different databases. Suggest me if you any other approach to achieve my requirement

Comment: Well I can suggest to read the two results sets into Java collections and then do that logic

Comment: without using collections I have to do this. with only resultsets

Comment: Why would you want to do it without collections? :) You can use the getArray method and work on the results. You realize that you need some place to store the found results anyway? If you delete from the result set it will delete the records from the database?

Comment: We are dealing with millions of records. If I use collections, there may be chance of getting memory/JVM issues. That is the reason I wanted to implement this without using collections

Comment: Where will you store the result then? If you iterate over the result sets with milions of rows maybe java is not the proper way to do it and you might consider some architectural changes. If it is not happening often you can use some ETL tool for that

Answer (score 1):

Your logic:

1. Assumes the records come in some order (which may or may not be true, depending on your SQL)
2. Consumes the entire result set 2 for each row of result set 1, which is unlikely your intent
3. Deletes things, which is also not what you mentioned in the question

Your question can be implemented easily as such:

```
Set<String> list1 = new HashSet<>();
while (table1ResultSet.next())
    list1.add(table1ResultSet.getString(1).toLowerCase());

while (table2ResultSet.next())
    list1.remove(table2ResultSet.getString(1).toLowerCase());

System.out.println(list1);
```

This will print all the values (without duplicates) that are present in the first result set, but not in the second.